# Using Linux kgdb over serial-on-LAN (SOL) using ipmitool

Tags: linux, kernel

Is it possible to use kgdb over BMC based SOL? I have ability to get to the serial console using ipmitool sol activate. However, I want to use it to connected gdb remotely in order to debug my Linux kernel module.

Comment: If you do kernel developpent/debugging you probably want to use a VM as your debugged machine **WILL** eventually break. Hence, you don't need to use a serial console. You can debug remotely using gdb though rpc, which is arguably easier and cleaner (see https://www.starlab.io/blog/using-gdb-to-debug-the-linux-kernel for instance)

Comment: Yeah I do use QEMU based environment also, but in this case I need to do PCI-E error injection (AER injection) on a physical PCI-E slot. I've posted my "wish" to add a gdb plugin to ipmitool on the ipmitool github. For now, I'll manage with printk and ftrace.

Comment: I have not done this myself, but perhaps you can make it work with the help of solproxy utility. For Linux, I found this: https://github.com/skuenzer/solproxy.

Comment: Looks promising @Aleksey. Thanks. I'll try it out soon (it's a shared machine and I won't get to use it until Friday).